# CSM & Solspace User

Tags: solspace-user, custom-system-messages

Does anyone know if the Custom System Messages add-on is compatible with Solspace User?

When I try to set an error template in the CSM interface (Register Member (On Error) for example) it does not seem to work since I'm using the register tag from Solspace User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a miscommunication on a deprecated error function for ExpressionEngine 2.6, and subsequently switched all of our addons to use CodeIgniter's built in error function, which does not work with CSM, instead of EE's built in output error, which CSM uses to redefine its errors.

We have looked deeper into the issue and realized our error and will be moving back to the CMS compatible error format on each next release of each of our addons.

Comment: Any idea when the update will be released?

Comment: Should be when EE 2.7 compatibility is added to User: http://www.solspace.com/blog/entry/compatibility_with_ee_2.7.0/

Comment: Just mentioning User is now EE 2.7-compatible: http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/change_log/#v3.4.5

Comment: It fixed most of the issues but I am still having problems with the register form: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/csm-solspace-user-register-form