# CSM, Solspace User & Register Form

Tags: solspace-user, registration, custom-system-messages

I can't seem to get the User register form to honor settings in Custom System Messages.

I had this issue before (see: [CSM & Solspace User](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13578/csm-solspace-user/13587?noredirect=1#comment15805_13587)) and was supposed to be fixed in the recent new release of User.

The new release seems to have fixed other forms but not the register form.

I have tried setting (12) Registration Form (On Error) & (13) Register Member(On Error) to redirect to a specific template in CSM, but I always get redirected to the General Error template.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post a ticket over at boldminded.com and I'll help you out. Please provide all version numbers and make sure you have CSM updated to the latest.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I was directing him to where he can get official support - If its a bug it needs to be handled via the official support channel, not here. This isn't a bug report forum.

Comment: I just flagged your comment before realizing what exactly you were pointing out. Apologies. Regardless, my answer is relevant - the answer is to take it to the official support forum especially when the author of the add-on in question responds to the question.

Comment: To be fair, that canned response SE displays when you flag an answer can come off as a bit rude. But on the other hand, this answer doesn't actually answer the question (it wouldn't help anyone else who comes across this question in a google search etc), so I've converted it to a comment.